# vscode about why I get two launch.json when debugging?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

When I tried to debug the app on chrome then the vscode generate another launch.json file. And they are both the same. **Which are the differneces of it?**

Also, I cannot run the app because I receive a message of the localhost refused to connect.
I‘ve downloaded Debugger for Chrome, and tried to add file in launch.json `"file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"`. But it is useless.

**I want to know how do I run the app on chrome correctly?**

[The detail of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkBZZ.png)

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: the 2nd `launch.json` in the `xxx-B-Master/.vscode` folder is not used, why do you have a `B-aster` folder inside the `B-Master folder`?

Comment: I solve the problem of two `launch.json`, but how can I debug the app on chrome? I still receive  localhost refused to connect.